# What's the reason for peoples to use properties with get; set; instead of fields?

Tags: c#, properties, field

I often see properties in classes, instead of fields. It looks like that:

```
class TestClass
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Why peoples do this? They could use fields instead. I see at least single pro there - we can pass fields with `ref` keyword into functions. Is there any pro for properties or other reasons to use them **like that**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason is encapsulation - the value can *only* be changed trough the corresponding properties, and this continues to be the case even if you later decide that the property shouldn't just return a value. Maybe you find that you'll want to fire an event when a value changes? If you've got a property, that's very easy. If you've got a public field, you need to make a breaking change.

In addition, properties can be virtual or declared in interfaces. And they can be declared read-only.

Oh, and it helps in debugging: You can set a breakpoint on the "set", if you want to know who is changing your value (unexpectedly).

Comment: There are also some usages strictly requiring properties, e.g. WPF data binding.

Comment: @KlausGütter That seems to be more a chicken-and-egg problem... If fields were the mainstream way of programming, WPF data binding would support them. When you use reflection (as WPF data binding does), looking for a property by name or a field by name is the same complexity, and it is something that can be cached so it won't slow down the code.

Comment: @xanatos I disagree wpf is a chicken-and-egg problem. If you want to have updates on your databindings you need to emit an event and that's exactly one of the scenario's mentioned in this answer where you need a property. Maybe they could have also supported fields for the cases where people are sure the values never change or they don't want the UI to reflect changes, but I can see why they decided to only support properties which work either way, so make for much more flexible wpf code.

Comment: TBH if you simply write `{ get; set; }` that doesn't encapsulate anything and it works the same like the field would. Also you can add `{ get; set; }` to an existing field and have a property instead without any backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas: Not 100% true. One scenario mentioned by the OP is using a member in a call to a method taking an out parameter. It's a rare case, but one that would break here. In addition, naming conventions typically don't allow that. Fields use different casing (and typcially a prefix), than properties.

Answer (score 1):

People use properties instead of fields mainly due to coding conventions. If it doesn't perform any *actual* encapsulation (in case of POCO), then there's not much of a difference in C#. Most of the times fields could be used instead of properties with no consequences whatsoever.

```
// This:
public string MyValue;
// Could be later on changed to this:
public string MyValue { get; set; }
// With no compatibility issues.
```

Although it's interesting to speculate why conventions are the way they are. In C# difference between properties and fields is mostly hidden from consumer standpoint. This is not necessarily the case in older languages. I.e. in Java you had to write getter and setter methods explicitly. So if you have a field in Java, and now you decide that you want to encapsulate it, then you would need to go over all usages of that field and use getters and setters instead. This could be even a bigger issue if you use dynamic library linking (that used to be popular style of deployment some time ago). Because of this it was easier to encapsulate fields from the start, so you wouldn't have backwards compatibility issues in the future. Naturally these conventions spread to other languages as well.

Comment: *With no compatibility issues* - not true. Changing a field to a property is a breaking change (the IL code accedding a field vs. property is quite different even if the C# source looks the same). Any client using this type will at least have to be recompiled.